# Select rows of a table where the involved table with its fields username and password was matched

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I know this is a confusing question.

I have two tables, **agents** and **clients**. Each table has field **id, name, username, password**

I have a login page where it selects **username** and **password** only to the **client** table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
```

what I want to do is to check in both table clients and agents table the username and password and then if one of the table has returned true, say it's agents table, it will select all the fields in the agents table.

*This is my current code*

```
$user = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$user = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$user);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<div class='warn' align='left'><embed src='icons/x-01.png'><div class='txt'>Invalid Username or Password!</div></div>";

} else {

    $fullname = $row['firstname'] . " " .$row['middlename']. " " . $row['lastname'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $fullname;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    echo "<script>window.open('myaccount.php','_self')</script>";

}
```

Comment: Two login screens or an option to specify what type of user you are would be better than looking in two tables. I also think it would also be a good idea to just have one users table that includes the users' types (a column with these values: client, agent, or both).

Answer (score 0):

If the table structures are the same, you could use a union query to bring back results from either:

```
SELECT id, name, username, password
FROM clients
WHERE username = <username> AND password = <password>

UNION

SELECT id, name, username, password
FROM agents
WHERE username = <username> AND password = <password>
```

You'd need to check to see whether you had more than one row returned though, and decide which table wins in the instance that you have more than one.